# Is there any advantage to removing event listeners in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am using jQuery quite heavily in a ASP.NET WebForms application to handle anything client-side that isn't application-critical (eg. on the fly validation, animations, general fluff and pretty stuff).

Within this solution, I am using update panels, so the main page rarely gets refreshed.  As such, event listeners can get bound on each asynchronous postback.

- With this in mind (or in any other typical circumstances), is there any advantages to using `.off` to remove event listeners on elements that I know are not going to be active at that time?
- Is the standard browser going to suffer much, if any, performance degradation if I leave the event listeners active, or will it only be noticeable at absolute extremes?
- Should I just unbind (`.off`) when I bind (`.on`) at high-level elements such as `body`?

What is the best way to handle (if required) unused event listeners in a scenario where they are being bound and unbound multiple times over the life-cycle of a single web-page?

If you have any tests that show if browsers slow down with numerous event listeners, please let me know.  Proven numbers would be perfect if anyone has them.

Comment: you'd be best off doing some testing with your application to see if you encounter performance issues. i think this is too broad to answer meaningfully. `.off()` wouldn't exist if it didn't solve some problems, so there probably is benefit to using it.

Comment: When you remove elements, jQuery automagically unbinds any jQuery bound event handlers, so that's one case where you don't need .off. One case where you DO need .off is when you are binding a new event handler to an element that already has the event handler, however, in that case it's likely better to avoid binding it again.

Answer (score -1):

Leaving inactive event listeners will definitely show negative impact on performance. It is definitely a better practice to off unnecessary event listeners.

I would also suggest you to use scope while binding event listeners like

```
$(".demo").on("click.test", function(){ ... });
```

Here I have scoped the `click` event with `test` so that when I do

```
$(".demo").off("click.test");
```

any other demo class having an on click listener will not get switched off.

Comment: Wish SO makes users downvote only after they comment on the reason.

Comment: *"Leaving inactive event listeners will definitely show negative impact on performance"* in some scenarios, sure, but not always. you'd have to have a pretty large number of extra event listeners in some cases for this to have any impact. It's usually better to design the code around the automatic cleanup that jQuery does when an element is removed.

Comment: Let's say I have an event listener to my class. It takes 300ms to run that snippet. If I off my event listener, I suppose it may bring a difference of 1ms. I understand it is not much of a difference but definitely it is some difference. 

I am failing to see in which case does switching off event listeners does not make any difference.

Comment: any *perceivable* difference.